# Tableview does not show the correct data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a tableview with search function. I have a function which takes a look at the first letter of each item. Then for each unique letter it adds it inside another array. So it adds the letter 'S' only one time if their are items inside that starts with an 'S' .

Then with this array I am gonna build my sections and rowsForSections.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int rows = 0;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        //---get the letter in each section; e.g., A, B, C, etc.---
        NSString *alphabet = [firstIndex objectAtIndex:section];
        //---get all states beginning with the letter---
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
        NSArray *names = [self.filteredListContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        //---return the number of states beginning with the letter---
        rows =  [names count];
    }
    else
    {
        //---get the letter in each section; e.g., A, B, C, etc.---
        NSString *alphabet = [firstIndex objectAtIndex:section];
        //---get all states beginning with the letter---
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
        NSArray *names = [self.listContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        //---return the number of states beginning with the letter---
        rows =  [names count];
    }
    return rows;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    int rows = 0;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        rows = [filteredFirstIndex count];
    }
    else
    {
        rows =  [firstIndex count];
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Here is my CellForRowAtIndex

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"list content %@",[listContent valueForKey:@"name"]);
    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    /*
     If the requesting table view is the search display controller's table view, configure the cell using the filtered content, otherwise use the main list.
     */
    Contact *contact = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        contact = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        contact = [self.listContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = contact.name;
    return cell;
}
```

**Problem**
Here is a screenshot with my problem. Because a picture says more then a 1000 words.

[image]

Hope that anyone can help me!

Kind regards!

Comment: Can you send me a sample project that shows the issue?
I will fix it and send back to you.

Comment: That's not the way stackoverflow works. Maybe you can give some suggestions of what you think is going wrong ?

Comment: It is difficult to guess in this much code..

Comment: why do you have two table views here?

Comment: I don't have two tableviews. I have 2 Arrays, one with all my items and one with the items after search.

Comment: Try to go through you program in debug mode, set break points and add logs.

Comment: what is this then
`if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)`

Comment: That's for using the search display controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines makes the issue:

```
    contact = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    contact = [self.listContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Because you are displaying the names in sections.

**In each sections the `indexPath.row` value begins from 0.**

That's why you are getting this result.

The below is not a good solution. But for an example I'm posting it. (It'll cause performance issues)
Use it in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSString *alphabet = [firstIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
NSArray *names = [self.filteredListContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
contact = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: @StefGeelen: i have added a solution, please check it also

Comment: @StefGeelen: with pleasure :)

Comment: @StefGeelen: instead of writing this in cellForRowAtIndexPath make names array as global and assign it in the numberofRowsInSection (you done that already)